# What's the corresponding standard function of atoi in clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

In visual lisp, you can use `(atoi "123")` to convert `"123"` to `123`.  It seems there is no "atoi" like function in clisp ?

any suggestion is appreciated !

---

Now i want to convert `'(1 2 3 20 30)` to `"1 2 3 20 30"`, then what's the best way to do it ?

`parse-interger` can convert string to integer, and how to convert integer to string ?  Do i need to use `format` function ?

```
(map 'list #'(lambda (x) (format nil "~D" x)) '(1 2 3)) => ("1" "2" "3")
```

But i donot know how to cnovert it to `"1 2 3"` as haskell does:

```
concat $ intersperse " " ["1","2","3","4","5"] => "1 2 3 4 5"
```

Sincerely!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Common Lisp, you can use the [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) function for this purpose:

```
> (read-from-string "123")
123 ;
3
```

As you can see, the primary return value is the object read, which in this case happens to be an integer. The second value—the *position*—is harder to explain, but here it indicates the next would-be character in the string that would need to be read next on a subsequent call to a reading function consuming the same input.

Note that `read-from-string` is obviously not tailored just for reading integers. For that, you can turn to the [`parse-integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_parse_.htm) function. Its interface is similar to `read-from-string`:

```
> (parse-integer "123")
123 ;
3
```

Given that you were asking for an analogue to `atoi`, the `parse-integer` function is the more appropriate choice.

---

Addressing the second part of your question, post-editing, you can interleave (or "intersperse") a string with the [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_format.htm) function. This example hard-codes a single space character as the separating string, using [the `format` iteration control directives](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/22_cgd.htm) `~{` (start), `~}` (end), and `~^` (terminate if remaining input is empty):

```
> (format nil "Interleaved: ~{~S~^ ~}." '(1 2 3))
"Interleaved: 1 2 3."
```

Loosely translated, the format string says,

> For each item in the input list (`~{`), print the item by its normal conversion (`~S`). If no items remain, stop the iteration (`~^`). Otherwise, print a space, and then repeat the process with the next item (`~}`).

If you want to avoid hard-coding the single space there, and accept the separator string as a separately-supplied value, there are a few ways to do that. It's not clear whether you require that much flexibility here.